# counter that increment every period even when app is killed

Tags: android

If you think of stratigy game like red alert or clash of clans, there is always building you put on the map that would generate money (say certain $5 every 1 min).

I am trying to do the same same in which a counter is incremented by 5 every 1 min. The way that comes to mind is by having a handler with postDelayed which calls itself every min and increment the money. The problem is that if the app is put in the background, it might get killed and the timer is no longer running.

Would a better option be to have an alarmManager which is scheduled at certain intervals to send a broadcast message? I find it to be an overkill (" I think").

How do games manage something like that?

Thank you

Comment: Why is it put on hold? It is a specific problem. I am given a scenario that I need design help with.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use time and calculate the the money based on time elapsed whenever you need to refresh the count rather than incrementing the money when you don't really need it.

Comment: And what if the app is in forground? I need to show the counter incrementing. In that case, I would need 2 implementations (Handler for forground and time-ellapsed when background? sounds like coordination is a mess unless I am missing something

Comment: Why do you need computation the background if you only actually retrieve the values when the app is running in foreground?

Comment: I guess you are right, it is not needed :)